# Angular.merge is not a function shows in angularjs chart integration

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chartist.js

I am using [angularjs chartjs](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#top). There is no problem. But when I am using `chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"` it shows the problem that **angular.merge** is not a function. I am using angularjs **version 1.3.3**. I have no option to upgrade angularjs now.
[image]

```
  <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-line"
       chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride">
    </canvas>
```